# Eliminate Duplicates of Custom Datastructure

Tags: python

```
class md5Check(object):
    """docstring for md5Check"""
    def __init__(self, md5, fullpath):
        super(md5Check, self).__init__()
        self.fullpath = fullpath
        self.md5 = md5

    fullpath = ""
    md5 = ""

imageFiles = list()
temp = md5Check(md5Sum, fullpath)
imageFiles.append(temp)
```

I would like to remove Duplicates in my List which consists of my md5Check-Datastructure. Duplicates are known by the class instances md5 variable. What is a good way to remove duplicates?

Comment: 32 character char = 076e3caed758a1c18c91a0e9cae336 eg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `md5` is hashable, you can use a `set` to keep track of seen `md5` values.

```
seen = set()
imageFiles = [x for x in imageFiles if x.md5 not in seen and not seen.add(x.md5)]
```

If you don't like the side effect:

```
seen = set()
imageFiles_new = []
for x in imageFiles:
    if x.md5 not in seen:
        imageFiles_new.append(x)
        seen.add(x.md5)
imageFiles = imageFiles_new
```

Comment: Exactly what i need, what do you mean by the side-effect?

Comment: @user1767754 the `and not seen.add(x.md5)` part is a little hackish because `add` returns None, which will be interpreted as `False` in a boolean context and `add` is only used for its side-effect of adding `x.md5` to `seen`.